# Spread arctic silver 5 thermal paste or not on laptop cpu?

Tags: cpu, thermal-paste

On my laptop CPU which is rectangular and small should I spread Arctic Silver 5 thermal paste? They seem to suggest spreading this paste on "Core™ i7 Mobile/Lap" which is the one I have. I have used the line method and big dot method in the past.
http://www.arcticsilver.com/intel_application_method.html
Many people dont recommend spreading the paste but arctic silver says otherwise on a laptop CPU. I am confused.

Comment: laptops often have thermal pads. If you use paste on a HSF designed for pads, the heatsink wouldn't sit properly on the processor.

Comment: This laptop has paste

Comment: People have proven that the amount of thermal paste you use has little to no effect.  As long as you cover the entire area of the CPU, the entire area of the metal lid, isn't the area of the CPU though.  Just follow the directions.

Comment: Run stress test and record the cpu temperature respectively for both methods. Go with whichever one with lower temperature. This is something you can verify on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Laptops often have thermal pads. If you use paste on a HSF designed for pads, the heatsink wouldn't sit properly on the processor. *If* there's paste on your heatsink as designed, it should be fine. In general though, it shouldn't really be necessary to redo the heat sink paste on a laptop in its usual working lifetime